# Ordering prepositional phrases

Tags: word-order, syntactic-analysis, prepositional-phrases

I have rewritten a sentence like the one below several times, and I could not seem to put the prepositional phrases in an order that sounded correct to me. Is there a better way to construct this particular sentence? Are there any solid rules for ordering several prepositional phrases?

> I have an interview on Friday with Joe Smith at ACME Inc for an Editor
>   II position.

Comment: I'd front the temporal PP, and help the reader with a comma: _On Friday, I have an interview with Joe Smith at ACME Inc, for an Editor II position_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word order in the English language is: Subject-Verb-Objects-Manner-Place-Time + first most detailed, then more general information.

Therefore, this is how I would phrase it:

> I have an interview with Joe Smith for an Editor II position at ACME
>   Inc on Friday.

Comment: Source? There are other orders that work just as well

Comment: Of course, @guifa, there are many to construct a sentence correctly. But SVOMPT is the most common method used to teach ESL students.

Comment: I order by pertinance/relevance, so I'm curious where ESL texts get that order from. Is it defined in the CGEL or other similar grammar?

Comment: I am afraid I can't cite the source, @guifa, as I am not a grammarian, but if you google "word order", SVO is the first thing that shows up. Besides, in school too (in India), we were taught to use the SVO method.

Comment: I don't think anyone would argue against SVO. It's the ordering of adjuncts that can't be so rigidly defined. For example http://books.google.com/books?id=OmjH711wDMQC&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=ordering+of+adjuncts+in+english&source=bl&ots=Zb5ShQjpMg&sig=m3ISLMc2saMPopTVh2K3bC73xBY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vaMYVKrKMci1ggTPpoGwDQ&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAw , in other parts of the book (and mentioned briefly in this page) there are other forces going on that dictate order.

Comment: It is a good source. I will certainly go through it and try to learn more. Hopefully, it will help me better understand the ordering of adjuncts.

Comment: @axomna I came across a post on another Stack Exchange site with several good comments regarding SVOMPT: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/is-the-svompt-word-order-necessary-in-creating-a-sentence