# How should I treat the conflict between the orders?

Tags: phrase-order

1. I always eat an orange in the park on Friday.
2. I always eat an orange on Friday in the park.

The first sentence means I eat an orange on Friday whenever I eat an orange in the park.

The second sentence means I eat an orange in the park whenever I eat an orange on Friday.

[Ordering prepositional phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196699/ordering-prepositional-phrases)

But prepositional phrases have to be in a specific order.

How can I treat the conflict between these? If I follow the order rule, the meaning will be changed, and if I follow the proper order for the meaning, the rule will be neglected.

Comment: I don't see any clear difference in meaning between the two versions.

Comment: The only slight difference is that in 1. you are emphasising that you eat an orange in the park rather than that you eat an orange on Friday whereas in 2. the emphasis is reversed.  The emphasis on location rather than time is rather more usual but there could be reasons for emphasising time.

Comment: No. The first sentence _can_ mean 'If I eat an orange in the park, it will only be on a Friday' but **defaults** to 'Every Friday, I eat an orange in the park.' In reading aloud, the first reading needs 'Friday' to be highly stressed. // The second sounds rather unnatural. Adding a comma after _Friday_ retrieves it, indicating that 'in the park' is de-stressed either to emphasise the locative by contrast, or to indicate an afterthought.

Comment: If you read the linked answer, the ordering is just a guideline someone made up, it's not an inviolable rule.

Answer (score 1):

Never let the 'rules of grammar' interfere with either the meaning of your sentences nor their elegance. (I'll write no more about elegance since much of that is opinion-based.). Yes, there are some rules which, if broken, change the meaning of a sentence, eg

> *man bites dog* is not the same as *dog bites man*

but there are many many rules which can safely be ignored, and which should be ignored if following them results in a wrong sentence.  Rules such as those governing the order of adjectives, or of prepositional phrases, are rules which can be ignored.  Consider:

> *the hairy blue dog* and *the blue hairy dog*

The first version follows the usual rule for ordering of adjectives, the second doesn't and has a slightly different meaning which may be exactly what is required in some circumstances.

Personally, I don't see the differences between your two sentences that you do, but my advice is ignore the rules for ordering prepositional phrases if they interfere with the story you are telling.

Comment: In other words, the 'rules' of grammar should not be thought of 'law-of-the-land' type rules but as 'as-a-rule' type rules.  There is a scale between 'just about everyone always', through 'many people often/sometimes' to 'few people or nobody ever' (and even 'one literary genius once brilliantly').  A case of the latter is "The sun was shining on the nothing new". (the opening sentence of Samuel Beckett's novel 'Murphy'.  A schoolboy I knew once cribbed it to begin a story for homework.  It came back from the teacher with 'the' crossed out in red ink, correcting a nobel prize laureate.

Comment: ... or preventing a copyright court case.